# Inner class Exception

Tags: java

I am getting some "Stack Over Flow"  Exception while I am executing below code.
I am making an "Anonymous Inner class".

```
public class Prac_RegularInnerClass {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Child1 c1=new Child1();
        c1.method4();
    }
}

class Parent1{
    public int z=10;
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("We are in Method 1!!!!!!!!!\n\n");
    }

    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("We are in Method 2!!!!!!!!!\n\n\n");
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent1{
    //Anonymous Inner class.
    Parent1 p1=new Child1(){
        public void method1()
        {

        }
    };

    public void method4()
    {
        p1.method1();
        p1.method2();

    }
}
```

I have made parent class Parent1. I have made a chile class Child1.
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be because within Child1 in construction phase you are setting the p1 property as an anonymous subclass of Child1 itself, which makes a new Child1 object instantiate, which makes a new Child1 object instantiate, which makes a new Child1 object instantiate, which makes a new Child1 object instantiate, and so on.

Instead that, either assign new objects after constructing them or assign an object of a  different type which doesn't end in recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you create an instance of `Child1`, it creates an anonymous instance of `Child1`, which creates another anonymous instance of `Child1` and so on and on..

Answer (score 1):

Because you are instantiate `Child1` class inside the `Child1` at block-level. You should have to instantiate anonymous class elsewhere other than constructors or blocks.

```
class Child1 extends Parent1{
    Parent1 p1;
    public void method4(){
       if(p1==null){
         p1=new Child1(){
           public void method1(){}
         };
        }
        p1.method1();
        p1.method2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created an infinite loop of creation. Everytime you create a `Child1`, it creates an inner `Child1` within it, which in turn contains a `Child1`, that has a `Child1` inside, that holds a `Child1`...